# Is mutex required in my case

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, mutex

I have two threads sharing a variable, but neither of them writes to that variable. I do understand that when two threads are dynamically reading or writing the variable, you do need a mutex. However, since, I am only reading the shared variable from either threads, do I still need to use a mutex?

P.S. Mine is a C++ program and I am using std::mutex.

Comment: You don't need a mutex (or any other synchronization) just for reading.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I guess he/she expects you to provide a sample code so that we can give better answer. for instance an int variable doesn't require lock but long long would

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variable is guaranteed not to be changed, then the reads don't need a mutex.

But if:

1. It's possible that the variable is written (by any thread) at the same time your threads are trying to read it
2. And, reads / writes are not atomic

Then you do need to synchronize.

Comment: a variable is not going to be in a half written state...it is being protected by memory access at hard ware level

Comment: Depends on the type of variable. This is C++ remember.

Comment: it doesn't matter what language it is, it is being protected by the hardware

Comment: Since when does hardware protect `operator =()` from anything?

Comment: BUS restricts only 1 thread from accessing ram at once

Comment: Steve, there is actually no hardware guarantee that any particular sized value will be protected from a race case.  There was actually a particularly interesting discussion about this when developing C++11 in the case of doing 1-byte writes on machines which only support 4-byte writes and nothing smaller.  C99 and C++11 have an integer size called atomic_int_t which is special because it indeed does have such a hardware guarantee (and will not be available on platforms which can never provide such a guarantee for any sized integer)

Comment: Not to mention other types. A "variable assignment" can also be a `std::vector`, which I hope we can all agree needs synchronization even for "just reading".

Comment: ok..let me rephrase then, as long as the variable can be written into memory with one store word operation then no lock needed

Comment: read word store word are guarantee to be atomic, you were not being clear about it

Comment: @Steve: the problem is that not everyone is aware of if and when a variable can be written with a single store. Can an `int` (32bits) be read/written in a single load/store? Maybe. Not if it is unaligned. Can a `bool` be read/written with a single load/store? What guarantees does that provide? The problem with the question is that *variable* is too vague a concept to reason about.

Answer (score 1):

As long as they are only reading from the variable, and the variable can be written/read with one store/read word operation then you don't.

Comment: ... and no other thread writes to the variable while the two threads read from it ... and as long as there is no `mutable` members that change inside the object as part of the read.